# Acces to directory whose owner is 1023 - add 1023 to www-data (?)

Tags: permissions, php

I have a directory named "/data/storage" whose owner is 1023 with "777" permission.
My goal is to have access to the content of this directory with a php application  = i want to acces with a user from "www-data" group ? 
My PHP application just wants to compress the contents of a part of this directory.

This user 1023 is not in /etc/passwd => my first idéa was to add it to www-data group.
But i can' add the 1023 user to www-data group because the user does not exist

```
$ sudo adduser 1023 www-data
adduser: The user `1023' does not exist.
```

I can't create this 1023 user :

```
$ sudo adduser --no-create-home --disabled-login --force-badname 1023
Allowing use of questionable username. Adding user `1023' ... Adding
new group `1023' (1001) ... Adding new user `1023' (1001) with group
`1023' ... useradd: group '1023' does not exist adduser:
`/usr/sbin/useradd -d /home/1023 -g 1023 -s /bin/bash -u 1001 1023'
returned error code 6. Exiting.
```

I can't change the directory owner "1023" because this system user is used by my wildfly application.

Any suggestions would be grateful appreciated 
Thank for your answer
Best regard

Comment: Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the group `1023` instead of a user:

```
$ sudo addgroup 1023 --force-badname
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run `ls -l` and see a *number* instead of a usual username in
the owner/group columns, then usually this means that you don't see the
user**name** but the numerical user**id**.

When Linux stores ownership of a file or directory, then it doesn't
store the username (like `pduck`) but the numerical userid (like `1050`)
instead. When we then issue `ls -l` or something similar the actual name
is looked up in `/etc/passwd` to display it, i.e. that file serves as
a mapping between userid and username.

When you now delete a user (`deluser pduck`) then the files the user
owned are still there and the metadata still refers to userid `1050`
as their owner. In lack of a mapping provided by `/etc/passwd` the
command `ls -l` now resorts to displaying the numerical id instead of
the name. That's why you see `1023` instead of a proper name.

The same applies when I build a tarfile on my computer and you unpack it
on yours: `tar` stores my userid (`1050`) and when you don't have a user
with that ID on your computer, then it will show `1050` as owner. (`tar`
has switches to change this behaviour, but that's the general idea.)

Now you have two possibilities: Either create a new account with a
given userid, `1023` in your case. Or change ownership of all files and
directories from `1023` to a user already created.

**Either: Create a user with ID 1023**

```
sudo adduser --uid 1023 --gecos "Perl Duck" --disabled-password pduck
Adding user `pduck' ...
Adding new group `pduck' (1023) ...
Adding new user `pduck' (1023) with group `pduck' ...
Creating home directory `/home/pduck' ...
Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
```

The switches `--gecos` and `--disabled-password` are optional; you may
omit them depending on your needs.

**Or: Change ownership of all files owned by 1023/1023 to user `barthez` and group `users`**

```
# Try first (i.e. just display what WOULD be done):
sudo find /data/storage -gid 1023 -exec echo chgrp users {} +
sudo find /data/storage -uid 1023 -exec echo chown barthez {} +

# actually change the ownership:
sudo find /data/storage -gid 1023 -exec chgrp users {} +
sudo find /data/storage -uid 1023 -exec chown barthez {} +
```

---

By the way, your

```
sudo adduser --no-create-home --disabled-login --force-badname 1023
```

created a user with *name* `1023` and *userid* `1001`. You had to use the 
`--force-badname` switch because the name looks like a number and may
puzzle both users and commands, especially when another user with proper
name but ID `1023` exists. Just think of `chown 1023 some_file`: did you
mean the textual username 1023 or the numerical ID 1023?
Thus this is considered a *bad name* and should be avoided.